# chromecast next video autoplay

Tags: video, web, chromecast

How is it possible to play next video automatically in Chromecasting?

One video is playing successfully but if there are more than one video it does not play the video.

How to create a queue for all the videos so that it can be automatically play next video?

I am using this API reference: [ChromeCast-Video](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [autoplay](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.QueueItem) property to achieve that.

Comment: I am not getting where to implement this

Comment: The above link has all the steps so unless you try it and if faied at some step then come back with specific question, I am not able to help.